# Revert rails console changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where I run rake tasks to add data from csv files. I need to test it from the console first. Is there a command in console to revert all the changes as its meant only for testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run the `console` in `sandbox` mode.

```
rails c --sandbox
```

Answer (score 2):

you can run:

```
bundle exec rails c -s
```

with `-s` option all commands are executed in sandbox mode. After exiting the console all commands will be rolled back. (you can use `--sandbox` or the shorter form `-s`)

Answer (score 2):

you can start the console in sandbox mode. It will wrap the whole session in a db transaction which will be rollbacked when you close the console.

To start it:

`rails console --sandbox`